# Converting WordPress site to PWA without using plugins

Tags: javascript, wordpress, progressive-web-apps

I have a little bit experience in WordPress but completely new to PWA.

Is there a way to convert WP website to PWA without using any plugins?

I noticed that most of the PWA plugins in WordPress are not working properly as what I have expected.

Appreciate your response on this question.

Comment: why are you not using super pwa plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/??

Answer (score 0):

**Download wordpress mobile pack Wordpress Plugin from Wordpress.org**

```
Go to the ‘Plugins’ / ‘Add new’ menu
Upload wordpress-mobile-pack.zip then press ‘Install now’.
Enjoy.
```

**Comprehensive setup**

A more comprehensive setup process and guide to configuration is as follows.

```
Locate your WordPress install on the file system
Extract the contents of wordpress-mobile-pack.zip into wp-content/plugins
In wp-content/plugins you should now see a directory named wordpress-mobile-pack
Login to the WordPress admin panel at http://yoursite.com/wp-admin
Go to the ‘Plugins’ menu.
Click ‘Activate’ for the plugin.
Go to the ‘WP Mobile Pack’ admin panel.
Go to the ‘Look & Feel’ tab. Choose color schemes, fonts and add your own logo and app icon.
Go to the ‘Content’ tab. Disable, enable or order categories and pages depending on what content you want to show in the mobile web app.
Go to the ‘Settings’ tab to choose a Display Mode and add your Google Analytics ID.
Access your site in a mobile browser and check if the application is displayed. If the app is not loading properly, make sure that the file exporting the content – http://yoursite.com/{your plugins folder}/wordpress-mobile-pack/export/content.php – can be accessed in the browser and doesn’t return a ‘404 Not Found’ or ‘403 Forbidden’ error.
You’re all done!
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I had a very negative assumptions upon looking up reviews of the plugin. Anyway, thanks for leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create PWA of WordPress or any responsive website with HTTPS enabled. No plugins are required.

1. Visit [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/)
2. Enter website URL
3. Fill App name, description, icon, theme color, etc.
4. Generate & download PWA (ZIP format)
5. Now follow the steps given in the [PWA documentation](https://github.com/pwa-builder/pwabuilder-web/blob/V2/src/assets/web/next-steps.md).